# HTML parsing with BeautifulSoup 4 and Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the resultlist of http://mobile.de.

First I tried it with the `HTMLParser` Class, but I got an error: `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: EOF in middle of construct`.

So I tried it with BeautifulSoup 4 which is better for non-valid websites, but the `<div>` I’m Searching for isn’t accessible, and I can’t tell if it’s my fault or the website’s.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib
    import socket

    searchurl = "http://suchen.mobile.de/auto/search.html?scopeId=C&isSearchRequest=true&sortOption.sortBy=price.consumerGrossEuro"
    f = urllib.urlopen(searchurl)
    html = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for link in soup.find_all("div","listEntry "):
        print link
```

`listEntry` is the `<div>` with the result of the cars. But it seems that he isn’t parsing `<form id="parkAndCompareVehicle" name="parkAndCompareVehicle" action="">`. I can’t find the form in the soupobject.

Where is the fault?

Comment: What do you get if you try the following for loop instead? — `for link in soup.find_all("form", id="parkAndCompareVehicle")`? (See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs))

Comment: I get nothing. I also tried with find_all("form") and i only get the 2 others.

Comment: hmm `soup.find_all('form', id='parkAndCompareVehicle')` returns the form for me

Comment: It looks that bs3 is working for me with `for link in soup.find_all("form", id="parkAndCompareVehicle")`. But i can use my `print(link.get('href'))` to get the links. Cant find something similar in the documentation of version 3.o, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'listEntry '}):
    print link
```

Attributes are specified in a dictionary -`findAll(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)`

==========

upd. Sorry it seems in bs4 you can do that way as well.

As for the fault, the form you're looking for is not in the results because it encloses listEntries as far as I can see.

What's wrong with that:

```
form = soup.find('form', id='parkAndCompareVehicle')
print len(form.find_all('div', 'listEntry '))
```

Comment: That’s the stuff — see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)

Comment: It looks (findALL) that u mean BeautifulSoup3, but iam using Version 4. If i use find_all('div','btn') i get the the content of the btn-div. That isnt the fault. see [doku bs 4.0](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Comment: `print len(form.findAll('div', 'listEntry '))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'` But bs3 seems to work, i only need now to get the href out of it. Any idea to this ? in bs4 its easy with `.get('href')`....

Comment: @user1010775: Same get, or even simpler - soup.a['href']. But [this code with find_all](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/573475/) does work for me (correctly prints 20)! Maybe they banned you or something?)

Comment: If they banned me, i couldnt get it with bs3, i got it working now. thanks to all!